# Big O Notation of this BinaryHeap code

Tags: c#, big-o

I'm trying to determine the Big O notation of two methods that are based on Jim Mischel's [BinaryHeap class](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789).

```
public void Add(T item) {
    int i = _items.Count;
    _items.Add(item);
    while (i > 0 && _items[(i - 1) / 2].CompareTo(item) > 0) {
        _items[i] = _items[(i - 1) / 2];
        i = (i - 1) / 2;
    }
    _items[i] = item;
}

public T Remove() {
    T firstItem = _items[0];
    T tempItem = _items[_items.Count - 1];
    _items.RemoveAt(_items.Count - 1);
    if (_items.Count > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < _items.Count / 2) {
            int j = (2 * i) + 1;
            if ((j < _items.Count - 1) && (_items[j].CompareTo(_items[j + 1]) > 0)) ++j;
            if (_items[j].CompareTo(tempItem) >= 0) break;
            _items[i] = _items[j];
            i = j;
        }
        _items[i] = tempItem;
    }
    return firstItem;
}
```

For the `Add` method, I believe it's `O(log(n))` since the loop appears to be of the form:

```
for(int i = n; i > 0; i=(i-1)/2);
```

And for the `Remove` method, I believe it's `O(log(log(n))` since the loop appears to be of the form:

```
for(int i=0; i < n/2; i = (2*i)+1);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to involve working code.

Comment: What is the type of `_items`? because the methods are manipulating it.

Comment: @xanatos It's a List; `List<T> _items`.

Comment: Should be migrated to programmers.stackexchange. See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=big-o